# How can i write a Template of HTML and create that HTML file with custom usernames as files_names when the API endpoints are hit in PHP?

Tags: php, html, backend

So basically i need that when user registers in my Android App i will make a POST request with user Name and company Name that they wanted and i will create a html page with that data in the HTML Template. and webpage will be visible like this -> [www.main-website.com/username](http://www.main-website.com/username) [main-website.com is the domain that i have bought]

So what I did , is that I created a variable that stores the HTML Template with custom changes by adding php variables in-between.And then created a file.html. Check this code {and also If you know a better way to do this thing pls suggest [main idea -> userAuthenticate -> webpage created with username and company name as  tags (this is protoype) ]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['companyName'])){
        $user_name = $_POST['userName'];
        $company_name = $_POST['companyName'];
    }
    
    $my_var = <<<EOD
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is  $user_name  </h1>
        <h2>My company name is  $company_name </h2>
    </body>
    </html>
    EOD;
    
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.php","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$my_var);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: > `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
This line in the code is added by mistake Pls ignore it

Comment: And everything is done in PHP

Comment: Typically what one would do would be to use a GET variable disguised by a rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file that maps, for example, a querystring parameter such as username to the username fetched from the database. ie: `?username=fred` would have a rewrite rule that allowed you to enter `main-website.com/fred` in the address bar. The GET variable `username` would be used in your sql query

Comment: In my code Nothing is happening

Comment: In my Android app i am using Firebase , so is there any way to use that same database with php also to generate the the webpage.

Comment: In the above, if it worked, you would overwrite `myText.php` each time this is run rather than create a new html file

Comment: And can You pls elaborate your answer because I am new to php so not catching all ur words pls

Comment: Pls write all steps point by point so i can do this task plsss

Comment: And can you pls tell me Why the code is not giving any output ?

Comment: Do you wish to generate a new html page for EACH user or have a single page that loads the pertinent user data when they login? btw: I know nothing about Firebase - I have never used it.

Comment: yes create new html pages ,

Comment: Okay no problem for firebase , do it with mysql

Comment: I would advse against generating new HTML pages per user. With a few users OK - but if you need to change the style or add more content you need to edit each page. If you have thousands of users that will drive you to despair. Usually the page draws the content dynamically based upon user login - one single page would suffice for ALL users

Comment: See i want to list every user's products in each page ,

Comment: there will be a share feature in android app , so basically user shares link

Comment: so which is best option you do on that